# Scope of System.setProperty

Tags: java, android, scope, system

What's the scope of [System.setProperty](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) in Android?

If I set a property (say `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false")`), does it affect all apps in the system, the current app, the current task or the current thread only?

Where is this documented?

Answer (score 4):

Java "system" properties do not cross process boundaries, they are held in memory and are tied to a single instance of the virtual machine.  Therefore if you set a system property within application it will not be visible to other applications running on the device.

Comment: But would it be visible to all tasks of the same application?

Comment: No, I mean Android tasks: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask

Comment: How reliable is this information ? I will be using 'HTTP Persistent Connections' and have to change JVM property 'http.maxConnections', will this affect other applications running on the same JRE, or other applications running on the same Tomcat example ?

Answer (score 0):

Android Activities of the same application, if you don't specify otherwise in the Manifest.xml, will run in a default Process created for the application when it starts.

Each process runs in its own JVM. So the System.setProperty(), based on @mmccomb 's answer, will reach all Activities in the same Application except if you, on pupose, declare Activities to run in different Processes.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html